# Select rows per groups and with time conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
           A          B   C
0 2002-01-16 2002-02-28  HH
1 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  DX
2 2002-01-16 2002-02-28  TY
3 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  FY
4 2002-04-28 2002-04-30  PE
5 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  CO
6 2002-04-28 2002-04-30  OL
7 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  DS
```

I want to select , per each `A` group, rows whose `A` date are:

- Closest in time to `B` date.
- Greater than two days to `B` date.

Output should be:

```
           A          B   C
1 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  DX
3 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  FY
5 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  CO
7 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  DS
```

I´ve tried:

```
df['Diff'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).abs()
df.loc[df['Diff'] == df['A'].map(df.groupby('A')['Diff'].min())]
```

Comment: Is the first bullet point supposed to read clos*est* to?

Comment: Sorry... Edited

Comment: no worries - I just couldn't make the edit because it was too few characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df[df['Diff'] == df['A'].map(df[df.Diff > pd.Timedelta('2 days')]
                              .groupby('A')['Diff'].min())]
```

Output:

```
           A          B   C    Diff
1 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  DX 14 days
3 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  FY 14 days
5 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  CO 27 days
7 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  DS 27 days
```

Answer (score 3):

I will do it by two steps

```
s=df[((df.B-df.A).dt.days>2)]# 1st condition 
s[((s.B-s.A).dt.days.groupby(s.A).transform(lambda x : x==x.min()))]# 2nd condition 
Out[1396]: 
           A          B   C
1 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  DX
3 2002-01-16 2002-01-30  FY
5 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  CO
7 2002-04-28 2002-05-25  DS
```